# jQuery Exception while creating an Extension Method

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a jQuery extension method that is supposed to take a jQuery selection, go through each item and return a new jQuery object with (potentially) different (but related) items - this is what I have now

```
$.fn.associated = function (selector: string): JQuery
{
    return this.map(function(j, x)
    {
        var $x = $(x);
        if ($x.is(selector)) { return $x; }
        var children = $x.find(selector);
        if (children.isNotEmpty()) { return children; }
        return $x.closest(selector);
    });
}
```

When it returns, it is definitely a jQuery object (I checked whether it is an instanceof jQuery). However, when I do .attr on it, I get an exception saying that "a.getAttribute is not a function" - any ideas?

Comment: but isn't this in the extension already a jQuery?

Comment: What language are you using there? JS doesn't have the `: type` syntaxx